# Angular receive sse data

Tags: angular, typescript, flask, server-sent-events

I have a component and I want it to receive data from my backend server via sse (server side events)
but for some reason it doesn't.

When I go directly to api endpoint it shows that messages are coming over time (what I want), but when I call it via Angular it doesn't work.

Also backend shows that a endpoint was called on both cases.

Backend code (Flask):

```
@bp.route('/stream')
def stream_text():
    def generate_text():
        # Generate the text in sections
        sections = ['Section 1', 'Section 2', 'Section 3', 'Section 4']
        for section in sections:
            yield section + '\n'
            time.sleep(0.5)

    return Response(generate_text(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Frontend code (Angular)

```
let eventSource: EventSource = new EventSource('/api/chat/stream');  // url is correct
eventSource.onmessage = (ev: MessageEvent) => {
   console.log(ev.data)  // doesnt show
}
```

Angular to receive sse data and not all at once but over time

Answer (score 0):

When using EventSource you should handle messege events with the [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone), because they are happening outside of Angular.

```typescript
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";

// ...
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

// ...
let eventSource: EventSource = new EventSource('/api/chat/stream'); 
eventSource.onmessage = (ev: MessageEvent) => {
  this.zone.run(() => console.log('EVENT:', ev);
  // Handle the event the way you see fit
  /*
  this._zone.run(() => {
    this.myObservet.next(ev.data);
    this.store.dispatch(SomeActions.sseEvent({ data: ev.data })
  });
  */
}
```

Comment: this didnt work